# How to sort Pin 1 (Passive) of 'xx' component is not driven - KiCad ERC check

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematics, kicad

In DRC KiCad (4.0.7, release biuld), after doing ERC, there is error: 'ErrType(3): Pin connected to some other pins but no pin to drive it. Pin 1 (Passive) of component C5 is not driven (Net 49).'

How to solve this issue?

In my case C5 is connected to Atmega32 AREF pin.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are connecting a passive (C5) to an power input pin (AREF).  Since Atmega32 allows internal VREF, pin 29 should properly be labeled passive.  Since it is not, you can either change the library part or add a PWR flag to the line right next to pin 29.